# Rails. Начисление баллов пользователю за заполненные поля

Tags: ruby-on-rails

С целью мотивировать юзеров заполнять поля в профиле надо сделать систему баллов. У юзера изначально 0 баллов. Если он заполнил поле получил +10. Если убрал изменения -10. Код приведенный ниже работает, добавляет баллы при заполнении поля, и убирает если оно пустое. Но есть ошибка, баллы так же добавляются и при внесении изменений в поле. Как это можно решить?

```
before_save :add_score

def add_score
  if name_publ_changed?
    if name_publ.blank?
      self.score -= 10
    else
      self.score += 10
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вычислять score каждый раз, заводим массив с именами полей, которые нужно учитывать, подсчитываем количество очков при помощи итератера inject

```
before_save :add_score

def add_score
  self.score = [:name_publ, :content, :about].inject(0) do |sum, field|
    sum + (self[field].blank? ? 0 : 10)
  end
end
```

Comment: валидация есть не у всех полей. но это сработает если юзер будет заменять существующее значение поля на невалидное значение. если он заменит на валидное то так еж получит +10 баллов.

Comment: Вы правы, исправил свое решение на более корректное

Comment: Спасибо. Работает как надо.